# Subscript operator with AnyObject in Swift

Tags: swift, subscript, anyobject

I have observed that it is possible to use the subscript operator with `AnyObject` instances in Swift. For example:

```
let x: AnyObject = NSDictionary()

print(type(of: x["y"]))
```

This code produces the following output:

> `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Optional<Any>>`

The first part makes sense, because invoking any method on an instance of `AnyObject` is [defined](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html) to behave like an implicitly unwrapped optional. The rest of the output suggests that the subscript operator itself is defined to return `Optional<Any>`, which also makes sense, since it parallels the behavior of subscripts for dictionary instances.

I assume this is by design, but I haven't been able to verify it. Does anyone know if the behavior of the subscript operator for `AnyObject` is documented anywhere?

Comment: `let x: AnyObject = NSDictionary()` is insane. With the annotation you cast a - in terms of Swift - already quite unspecified type `NSDictionary` which is at  least recognized as key subscriptable to a completely unspecified type `AnyObject`. **`AnyObject` can not be subscripted at all**. If you are looking for a language which **does not** care about types Swift is not a candidate.

Comment: It's just an example. Obviously you'd never create an `NSDictionary` and assign it to `AnyObject` in practice. However, it's perfectly valid to end up with an instance of `AnyObject` in Swift; for example, when using `JSONSerialization`. And yes, you absolutely can subscript `AnyObject` - hence, my question.

Comment: When deserializing JSON you don't need `AnyObject / Any` at all. JSON contains only two collection types, array `[Any]` and dictionary `[String:Any]`. The former can be subscripted by index, the latter by key. The main concept of Swift is the strong type system so never cast or annotate a type to a more unspecific one unless the compiler tells you to do.

Comment: I'm aware of how JSON and Swift's type system works. I'm simply asking if the behavior of the sequence operator with AnyObject is documented anywhere.